# How do I exclude test functions from code coverage when using kcov?

Tags: rust, kcov

By default, kcov includes all sources files, including test functions, in its code coverage results. This skews the reported coverage rate. How do I tell kcov to exclude test functions?

For example:

```
#[test]
fn foo() {
    ...
}
```

kcov reports coverage data for `foo`, but I want to exclude it.

Comment: Please provide more info about how you are invoking kcov.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have your testing code in different files and use the `kcov` arguments `--exclude-path=./test` (for the integration tests) or `--exclude-pattern=_test.rs` (if you move all your tests for foo.rs into foo_test.rs).

Another way is to use the `kcov` argument `--exclude-region='#[cfg(test)]:#[cfg(testkcovstopmarker)]'` and make sure that each file either only has tests at the end and no non-test code following it or adds the stop marker `#[cfg(testkcovstopmarker)]` with the necessary unused definition after it to make `rustc` happy. (`kcov` finds the start and end string for a region anywhere in a line.)

(There is also the possibility to exclude lines based on a string they contain, but that won't work for excluding tests in Rust.)